# Getting extra data in ajax in Yii2

Tags: php, json, ajax, yii2

i am getting data from the ajax call but also getting unnecessary data like all the data from my php files as you can see in the image below. How can I solve this issue?
[image: image showing json data but with unnecessary data]

### controller file

```
    public function actionAllDrivers()
    {
    $query = new Query;

    $query  ->select(['*']) 

            ->from('driver')

            ->join(  'INNER JOIN',

                    'car',

                    'car.reg_no = driver.reg_no'

                );

    $car2 = $query->all();
    echo json_encode($car2);
    return $this->render('AllDrivers', ['car2'=>$car2,
    ]);
```

### PHP file

```
    <?php
    $script = <<< JS
        $.get('index.php?r=car/all-drivers',function(data)
        {
           //dataJson = $.parseJSON(data);
           alert(data);
        });
    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering the view after echoing the json. Simple `exit` will suffice, Check the answer

```
 if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
 {
     echo json_encode($car2);
     exit;
 }
```

Comment: with 'exit' the blank page is shown with only json data on it. All other views are not shown

Comment: @SaadMahmood Updated the answer, Please check if it works for you

Comment: if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        {
            echo json_encode($car2);
            exit;
        }    //this is correct